# listing object with specific tag using django_taggit

Tags: django, django-views

I have a blog app that uses [django_taggit](https://github.com/alex/django-taggit). My `HomePageView` subclasses `ArchiveIndexView` and works well.

Now I'd like the following link to work: `http://mysite.com/tag/yellow` and I'd like to use the `ArchiveIndexView` generic class and pass in a modified queryset that filters on tag_slug. I want to do this because I want to use the same template as the homepage.

My `urls.py` is

```
url(r'^$', HomePageView.as_view(paginate_by=5, date_field='pub_date',template_name='homepage.html'),
    ),

url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'tag_view'), # I know this is wrong
```

My `views.py` is

```
class HomePageView(ArchiveIndexView):
"""Extends the detail view to add Events to the context"""
model = Entry

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(HomePageView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['events'] = Event.objects.filter(end_time__gte=datetime.datetime.now()
                                             ).order_by('start_time')[:5]
    context['comments'] = Comment.objects.filter(allow=True).order_by('created').reverse()[:4]
    return context
```

I realize I'm lost here, and would like some help in finding out how to create a new class `TagViewPage()` that modifies the queryset by filtering on tag_slug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key thing is to override the `get_queryset` method, so that the queryset only includes returns entries with the chosen tag. I have made `TagListView` inherit from `HomePageView`, so that it includes the same context data - if that's not important, you could subclass `ArchiveIndexView` instead.

```
class TagListView(HomePageView):
    """
    Archive view for a given tag
    """

    # It probably makes more sense to set date_field here than in the url config
    # Ideally, set it in the parent HomePageView class instead of here.
    date_field = 'pub_date'

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        Only include entries tagged with the selected tag
        """
        return Entry.objects.filter(tags__name=self.kwargs['tag_slug'])

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """
        Include the tag in the context
        """
        context_data = super(TagListView, self).get_context_data(self, **kwargs)
        context_data['tag'] = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=self.kwargs['tag_slug'])
        return context_data

# urls.py
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', TagListView.as_view(paginate_by=5, template_name='homepage.html')),
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me with a few edits. Needed to add the paginate_by and self.kwargs['tag_slug']. Also, I think we can get rid of the get_context_data(self, **kwargs) function completely if you are subclassing from HomePageView.

Comment: I've fixed my answer to use `self.kwargs['tag_slug']`. As you say, the `get_context_data` method isn't required unless you want the tag in the template context.

Comment: instead of this line context_data['tag'] = Tag.objects.get(slug=self.kwargs['tag_slug']) better to use get_object_or_404

Comment: @soField - I don't think that's required in this case. If the tag doesn't exist, then there won't be any `Entry` objects tagged with it, so the view will return 404 anyway.

Comment: @Alasdair i got doesnotexist exception

Comment: @soField my mistake. You are correct, my code above would have raised `DoesNotExist`. It's fixed now.